# How to find the analytics page for a Google reCAPTCHA registration

Tags: google-developer-tools, grecaptcha

This might be a stupid question, but the Google developer portal is horrible...

I've recently signed up for an API key pair for Google's reCAPTCHA service (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha)

But it seems that after the initial signup, the Google developer portal will simply not display you a link to your existing recaptcha registrations. Can maybe someone give me a link to access the Settings/Analytics screens for a recaptcha registration. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just use https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/ to access my analytics